# Tableau Count Distinct for a combination cell

Tags: sql, tableau-api

I have to find a count for a combination of columns:

```
JobsName    date        check       calculatedField 
Job1        2/2/2020    check1        1
Job1        2/2/2020    check2        1
Job1        3/2/2020    check1        2
Job3        4/2/2020    check1        3
Job3        4/2/2020    check2        3
Job3        4/2/2020    check3        3
Job4        5/2/2020    check3        4
```

add 1 to the caucluatedField whenever a JobsName has a new date on which it ran.

Answer (score 0):

Iy your database supports window functions, you can just use `dense_rank()`:

```
select
    t.*,
    dense_rank() over(order by date) calculatedField
from mytable t
```